# how could read and create in APIView if Employee is exist

Tags: django-rest-framework

I want to insert data into Track but if an employee exists
this is my CBV

```
class TrackList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
def get(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
    employee = Employee.objects.filter(name=kwargs.get('name'), code=kwargs.get('code'))
    if employee.exists():
        serializer_class = TrackSerializer
        data = Track.objects.values()
        return response.Response(data)
    return response.Response('Not Exit')
```

and, here is my url

```
path('track/<name>/<code>/',views.TrackList.as_view(),name = 'track_list'),
```

but it returns an error
*'TrackList' should either include a `serializer_class` attribute, or override the `get_serializer_class()` method.*

please help me. how could I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
class TrackList(APIView):
    http_method_names = ['get', ]
    def get(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        "your code here"
```

So basically you do not need generics